# How can I make NSFetchedResultsController event correctly when predicate values change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my Core Dara model, there is a single Session object that holds a single Order object (though other orders can be floating around in CoreData) and Order holds Purchases.  I've got an NSFetchedResultsController that fetches Purchases for the Order in the Session.

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"order.session = %@" argumentArray:@[session];
```

This works fine for fetching, but it doesn't call back the delegate methods for the fetched results controller in the case that the Order becomes detached from the Session. Is this just a failure in the NSFetchedResultsController, or is there a documented limitation?  More importantly, how can I get around that limitation in a clean way?

To be clear, the results controller always returns the correct result after calling `performFetch:` it's just not firing the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a "feature".  The fetched results controller tracks changes to its fetched objects, but as far as it's concerned those objects are unchanged - the only change is to the related Order object.  I think your best bet would be to use Key Value Observing of your Order object (or Session object) in order to be notified if they become "disconnected".